# Ruby super value when argument is missing in subclass

Tags: ruby, arguments, super

```
 class Bike
   attr_reader :gears

   def initialize(g = 5)
     @gears = g
   end
 end

class AnotherBike < Bike
  attr_reader :seats

  def initialize(g, s = 2)
    super(g)
    @seats = s
  end
end
```

Is it possible to create a AnotherBike instance 'AnotherBike.new' 
that will take default value for 'gears' from super when argument is not given?

so for e.g

```
my_bike = AnotherBike.new  
...
my_bike.gears #=> 5
my_bike.seats #=> 2

my_bike = AnotherBike.new(10)  
...
my_bike.gears #=> 10
my_bike.seats #=> 2

my_bike = AnotherBike.new(1,1)  
...
my_bike.gears #=> 1
my_bike.seats #=> 1
```

I am using Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change an order of args to make it little more elegant

```
class AnotherBike < Bike
  attr_reader :seats

  def initialize(s = 2, g = nil)
    g ? super(g) : super()
    @seats = s
  end
end

AnotherBike.new()
AnotherBike.new(4)
AnotherBike.new(4, 6)
```

to support your examples @Matzi answer will be ok

Answer (score 1):

Class:

```
class AnotherBike < Bike
  attr_reader :seats

  def initialize(g = nil, s = 2)
    g ? super() : super(g)
    @seats = s
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
AnotherBike.new(nil, 13)
```

It should work, but this can be a bit redundant.

Comment: I think `super` will pass all args if you won't pass it explicitly, so you should call `super()` like that

Answer (score 0):

Why not send a hash instead?

```
class Bike
   attr_reader :gears

   def initialize(attributes)
     @gears = attributes.delete(:g) || 5
   end
 end

class AnotherBike < Bike
  attr_reader :seats

  def initialize(attributes)
    @seats = attributes.delete(:s) || 2
    super(attributes)
  end
end
```

you have to call it as: `AnotherBike.new({:g => 3, :s => 4})`

Comment: Or `AnotherBike.new(g: 3, s: 4)` in Ruby **1.9**.

Comment: Not sure which version the OP is on!

Answer (score 0):

I might be drifting a little too far from the actual question, but it looks like you might gain from using composition instead of inheritance. I don't know what the context is though.

```
class Gears
  def initialize(count = 5)
    @count = count
  end
end

class Seats
  def initialize(count = 2)
    @count = count
  end
end

class Bike
  def initialize(gears, seats)
    @gears = gears
    @seats = seats
  end
end
```